# How can I get the choice "H2" back in the H2 consol?

Tags: h2

I accidentally deleted the entries for H2 (Embedded) and H2 (Server) from the H2 console. The dropbox shown below allows you to select the kind of database you want to connect to/create. There is a button that allows you to remove entries, and with it I deleted the ones for H2. I have uninstalled and reinstalled H2, but didn't get the database types I deleted. What do I do?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could remove [the file `.h2.server.properties` in the user home directory](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#console_settings), and then restart the H2 Console.

Comment: I just tried that (actually changed the name to xx.copy, but when I restarted the Console I got the same list. not a corrected one. And the h2.server.properties file had not been rebuilt.  There must be another .server.prop somewhere? But I have not been able to find one.

Comment: This is the only file. Please note there is a dot at the beginning of the file name (you wrote `h2.server.properties`, but it is `.h2.server.properties`). Maybe you didn't stop all instances of H2, or you have change it in the wrong directory (wrong user)?

Comment: I did notice the dot at the beginning, but I'll  look for the file in other locations.

Comment: Finally! Uninstalled. *Rebooted*. Reinstalled. All db types now appear in the Console.  I hadn't rebooted before.

Answer (score 0):

you cant delete package target and in the dashbord h2-console add in "driver class": org.h2.Driver
and in "JDBC URL": jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/your database
User Name:  your data base